# Pandas data manipulation, calculating a column value based on other rows of the same column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I wish to do a data manipulation as follows in a pandas dataframe:

```
a = {'idx': range(8),
     'col': [47,33,23,33,32,31,22,5],
     }

df = pd.DataFrame(a)
print(df)

idx col
0   47
1   33
2   23
3   33
4   32
5   31
6   22
7   5
```

My desired output is:

```
idx col desired
0   47  14
1   33  10
2   23  -10
3   33  1
4   32  1
5   31  9
6   22  17
7   5   5
```

The calculation is as follows.

[image]

Comment: Can you explain the logic? Where do all those numbers in the calculation come from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Same solution as @mozway with `numpy` (which is faster):

```
import numpy as np

df['desired'] = -np.diff(df['col'], append=0)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
   idx  col  desired
0    0   47       14
1    1   33       10
2    2   23      -10
3    3   33        1
4    4   32        1
5    5   31        9
6    6   22       17
7    7    5        5
```

For 10k records:

```
# @mozway
>>> %timeit df['col'].diff(-1).fillna(df['col'])
281 µs ± 14 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

# @GodIsOne
>>> %timeit df['col'] - df['col'].shift(-1, fill_value=0)
144 µs ± 4.18 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

# @Corralien
>>> %timeit (-np.diff(df['col'], append=0))
32.7 µs ± 951 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you need a reversed [`diff`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.diff.html), and [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
df['desired'] = df['col'].diff(-1).fillna(df['col'])
```

Output:

```
   idx  col  desired
0    0   47     14.0
1    1   33     10.0
2    2   23    -10.0
3    3   33      1.0
4    4   32      1.0
5    5   31      9.0
6    6   22     17.0
7    7    5      5.0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a = {'idx': range(8),
     'col': [47,33,23,33,32,31,22,5],
     }

df = pd.DataFrame(a)

df['col'] - df['col'].shift(-1, fill_value=0)

0    14
1    10
2   -10
3     1
4     1
5     9
6    17
7     5
Name: col, dtype: int64
```

---

```
df['desired'] = df['col'] - df['col'].shift(-1, fill_value=0)

   idx  col  desired
0    0   47       14
1    1   33       10
2    2   23      -10
3    3   33        1
4    4   32        1
5    5   31        9
6    6   22       17
7    7    5        5
```